# how to call something specific from a rest api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rest

I'm trying to call a specific stat from a rest API.

```
    {"5908":[{"name":"Riven's Cutthroats","tier":"CHALLENGER","queue":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5","entries":[{"playerOrTeamId":"5908","playerOrTeamName":"Dyrus","division":"I","leaguePoints":727,"wins":373,"losses":313,"isHotStreak":false,"isVeteran":true,"isFreshBlood":false,"isInactive":false}]},{"name":"Lee Sin's Soldiers","tier":"PLATINUM","queue":"RANKED_TEAM_5x5","entries":[{"playerOrTeamId":"TEAM-46c2da55-7d0d-11e5-91f5-c81f66ddabda","playerOrTeamName":"RetiredCrabbyPpl","division":"III","leaguePoints":0,"wins":4,"losses":2,"isHotStreak":false,"isVeteran":false,"isFreshBlood":false,"isInactive":false}]}]}
```

I want to get the `"tier":` value (Challenger in this case), but only if the `"queue":` type is `"RANKED_SOLO_5X5"`.

```
function getStuff() {
    var SUMMONER_ID = "";
    SUMMONER_ID = $('#theKey').val();

    if(SUMMONER_ID !== 0) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v2.5/league/by-summoner/' + SUMMONER_ID + '/entry?api_key={KEY}' ,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: {

        },
        success: function (json) {
          var user = SUMMONER_ID;

          var summonerRank = json[user].tier;

          document.getElementById("sRank").innerHTML = summonerRank;

        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert("error getting Summoner rank!");
        }
    });
  } else{}
}
```

right now i have this code but the only thing I get back is undefined. (The key I use has been hidden).

Answer (score 0):

The value at `json[user]` is an array. What your code is currently doing is trying to access a property named `tier` of the array object instead of one of the objects in the array.

You need to loop through the array and then test each object for your value

```
for(var i=0; i<json[user].length; i++){
   if(json[user][i].queue == 'RANKED_SOLO_5X5'){
      console.log(json[user][i].tier);
   }
}
```

Comment: this seems to still be giving the same undefined error.Even after trying to input in several diferent ways